# Compare 2 lists in testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to make a test stub to check if the AddProduct method works or not.

I am getting a list of all the Products from the database

```
List<Product> ProductsBeforePlusNewProd = new ProductsBL().getAllProducts().ToList();
```

Populating the new product to add

```
 Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.ProductName = ...
```

Adding the newProduct to the database

```
new ProductsBL().addProduct(newProduct);
```

Adding the same product to the list ProductsBeforePlusNewProd which will hold the previous products and the new one - (this is the expected result)

getting the whole list after adding the product to database

```
List<Product> ProductsAfter = new ProductsBL().getAllProducts().ToList();
```

Then this fails

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ProductsBeforePlusNewProd, ProductsAfter);
```

What am I missing here ? This is my first test stub

EDIT : Error message : CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)

Comment: Are you mocking your database interaction or is your test actually hitting the database?

Comment: Its happening on the actual database

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal.aspx _Two collections are equal if they have the same elements in the same order and quantity. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object._

Comment: Both collections have the same elements, in the same order and quantity

Comment: Does `Product` have a primary key which is assigned by the database? If so, the product you retrieve isn't equal to the one you added, because the primary key differs. Also `Product` would have to implement `IEquatable` as others already stated.

Comment: Product does have a primary key, but in both lists they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pascx64 already showed, you can implement `IEquatable` at `Product`. But if you don't want to (or can't) change the implementation of `Product`, you could implement an `IComparer`:

```
    public class ProductComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            // compare the two objects
        }
    }
```

You can than use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ProductsBeforePlusNewProd, ProductsAfter, new ProductComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will compare the list instances, not the items. I suggest you use IEnumerable.SequenceEquals (your item must implement equals)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal.aspx

Comment: Error here! I didn't see the CollectionAssert

Answer (score 0):

Two collections are equal if they have the same elements in the same order and quantity. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object. The values of elements are compared using Equals by default.
 Are you sure that the elements in the both collections are equal? You need to implement IEquatable in Product class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement IEquatable in your `Product` class :

```
public class Product : IEquatable
{
    public string ProductName;
    public bool Equals( object o )
    {
        Product other = o as Product;
        if( other == null ) 
             return false;
        return ProductName == other.ProductName;
    }
}
```

By default, the `CollectionAssert.AreEquals` will only check if the two references refer to the same object

Comment: is there a way to check for values only ?  I tried looping through each record but it still fails

Comment: What do you mean by values ?
If you implement IEQuatable you can check the value of `ProductName`